# navigation bar is missing

Tags: iphone, ios

Navigation bar is missing while pushing kalviewcontroller on button click.How to add navigation bar? so that it can be pop to view controller where its being pushed on button click.

```
kal = [[[KalViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
kal.title = @"Calendar of game";

kal.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self 
action:@selector(addEvent)] autorelease];
kal.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backToPrevious)]  
autorelease];

kal.delegate = self;
dataSource = [self init];
kal.dataSource = dataSource;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:kal animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE]` in you `viewDidLoad`(assuming you have created navigation controller).

Comment: when you are assuming that he has created a navigationController - so you have also assumed that he has his navigationController hidden? - you did not mention this assumption...